# Why we use general interface(GI)?

Tags: tibco

I am newer to the topic of GI.I just what to know why we are using GI,what is GI.

Answer (score 0):

General interface is a proprietary UI framework developed by TIBCO. It features AJAX and rich client experience. They used it for one of AMX BPM interfaces : Workspace, and made it available via licensing for implementation.

This was another time... back then multiple companies tried to suggest a (often proprietary) approach to rich client based + back-end calling web UI. Ajax was the rage... and everybody tried to impose a framework.

A lot of that changed in the following years, when some new tools emerged, like Google Web Toolkit (GWT), JSF, Wicket, etc.

Eventually, TIBCO itself would use GWT in a second BPM UI : Openspace.

Arguably, most of these framework looks complex and outdated when compared to the lighter,current web frameworks, such as : JQuery, Webix, etc. These are mostly done with Javascript.